# java inheritance and method

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

***I am having problems trying to compile following code based on this requirement:***

Given an existing class, BankAccount, containing: 
a constructor accepting a String corresponding to the name of the account holder.
a method, getBalance, that returns a double corresponding to the account balance.
a method withdraw that accepts a double, and deducts the amount from the account balance.
 Write a class definition for a subclass, CheckingAccount, that contains: 
a boolean instance variable, overdraft. (Having overdraft for a checking account allows one to write checks larger than the current balance).
a constructor that accepts a String and a boolean. The String parameter is used in the invocation of the superclass (BankAccount) constructor, while the boolean is used to initialize the overdraft instance variable.
a method, hasOverdraft, that returns a boolean. hasOverdraft returns true if the account supports overdraft.
a method, clearCheck, that accepts a double and returns a boolean. clearCheck will determine if the amount (of the check) can be cashed-- this will be the case if the amount is less than the balance in the account, or if the account allows overdraft. If the check can be cashed, clearCheck returns true, and also calls the withdraw method to update the account balance; otherwise, clearCheck returns false.

***Code:***

```
public class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {
private boolean overdraft; 

public CheckingAccount(String a, boolean overdraft) {
this.name = super.name;
this.overdraft = overdraft;}

boolean hasOverdraft() {if(overdraft); return true;}

boolean clearCheck(double checkAmount) {if(checkAmount < balance || hasOverdraft() == true); return true && withdraw();}
}
```

***Error:***

```
CheckingAccount.java:4: error: constructor BankAccount in class BankAccount cannot be applied to given types;
public CheckingAccount(String a, boolean overdraft) {
                                                    ^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
CheckingAccount.java:5: error: name has private access in BankAccount
this.name = super.name;
    ^
CheckingAccount.java:5: error: name has private access in BankAccount
this.name = super.name;
                 ^
CheckingAccount.java:10: error: method withdraw in class BankAccount cannot be applied to given types;
boolean clearCheck(double checkAmount) {if(checkAmount < balance || hasOverdraft() == true); return true && withdraw();}
```

Comment: Please show the `BankAccount` class...

Comment: its not part of the problem the problem assumes as it states given an existing class BankAccount

Comment: Of course, it is part of the problem. All your compiler errors relate to that class.

Comment: @gucciv12: It's part of the problem because the error messages are telling you that you're calling constructors and methods from `BankAccount` incorrectly.  To help you fix it, we would need to see how those constructors and methods are declared.

Comment: I have no visibility in to the Bank class it "exists"

Comment: What do you mean, you have no visibility into it?  If you're expected to compile against it, you obviously at least need the compiled class file available, ideally the source code too.  Do you have a javadoc for the class?  If you're missing this information, you need to go back to your instructor.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `BankAccount` does not have a visible no-argument constructor.  From the error message, it appears that it has a constructor that takes one argument: a `String`.

Therefore you must explicitly call the proper constructor in the constructor for `CheckingAccount`.  Usually this would look like this:

```
public CheckingAccount(String a, boolean overdraft) {
    super(a);
    this.overdraft = overdraft;
}
```

But really it depends what the `String` is supposed to represent, and what `a` is supposed to represent (that's an awfully non-descriptive name for a parameter).

Second, it appears that the `name` field in `BankAccount` is not visible.  What you're trying to do by assigning it to `this.name` doesn't make any sense anyways, because `name` is not a field that has been declared in `CheckingAccount`.

Third, `withdraw()` seems to require parameters, but you haven't provided any.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BankingAccount {
    protected String name;

    public BankingAccount(String n) { this.name = n; }
}


public class CheckingAccount extends BankingAccount {
    protected boolean overdraft;

    public CheckingAccount(String n, boolean overdraft) {
        super(n);
        this.overdraft = overdraft;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CheckingAccount extends BankAccount {                

CheckingAccount(String name, boolean overdraft) {                    
super(name);                    
this.overdraft = overdraft;                }                

boolean hasOverdraft() {return overdraft;}                

boolean clearCheck(double amount) {
if (getBalance() >= amount || overdraft) {withdraw(amount);return true;}return false;} boolean overdraft;}
```